# Getting rid of Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Can I uninstall Windows 10 and go back to Windows 7? I am locked out of 10 at the login password screen. Even when I was in there, I could not download pictures from my camera to the laptop. I was crazy for installing it.

Comment: If you cannot log into the machine then you cannot go back to the previous version of Windows.

Comment: Actually you can, use your factory recovery media.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you upgraded within the last two weeks, and are able to remember
   your login password, you can can select the option to [Go Back to
   Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/going-back-to-windows-7-or-windows-81) in settings. This is the easiest method.

   > If it’s been less than a month since you upgraded to Windows 10, you can go back to your previous version of Windows by going to
   >   Settings > Update & security > Recovery  and selecting either Go
   >   back to Windows 7 or Go back to Windows 8.1. This won't affect your
   >   personal files, but it will remove any apps you installed after the
   >   upgrade to Windows 10.
2. Alternately, you can use another computer to create a Windows 7
   installation USB key or DVD via Microsoft's website [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7). You
   will however need a Windows 7 product key. There may be one written
   on your computer, or you may be able to contact the computer's
   manufacturer. Afterwards, you'll need to restart your computer and
   have it boot from the USB/DVD the next time it starts up. Methods
   for doing this vary depending on your computer, but the most common
   way is to repeatedly press F12 as the computer is booting.